# How to find particular solution to this system of two masses connected by a spring with constant applied forces? Does an analytic solution exist?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, coupled-oscillators

This question comes from review I'm doing on my own, so it's not any homework question. I thought this question would be easy to solve, but I seem to be stuck and I am having second thoughts, so I'm hoping for some feedback.

Consider two masses $m_{1}, m_{2}$ in 1D with a spring of spring constant $k$ and natural length $\ell$ connecting the two masses. Suppose further, there are constant forces $F_{1}, F_{2}$ acting on masses $m_{1}, m_{2}$, respectively. No friction or drag is at play. Does a full analytic solution exist?

[image]

The system of differential equations is
\begin{align*}
m_{1}\ddot{x}_{1} &= F_{1} + k(x_{2} - x_{1} - \ell), \\
m_{2}\ddot{x}_{2} &= F_{2} - k(x_{2} - x_{1} - \ell).
\end{align*}
By rearranging, we have
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\ddot{x}_{1} \\ \ddot{x}_{2}
\end{pmatrix} - 
\begin{pmatrix} 
-\omega_{1}^{2} & \omega_{1}^{2} \\ \omega_{2}^{2} & -\omega_{2}^{2}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1} \\ x_{2}
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} a_{1} \\ a_{2} \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
where $a_{1} = F_{1}/m_{1} - \omega_{1}^{2}\ell$, $a_{2} = F_{2}/m_{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\ell$, and $\omega_{i} = \sqrt{k/m_{i}}$ ($i=1, 2$). I'm able to solve for the homogenous solution, which would be
$$ \vec{x}(t) = A\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + B\begin{pmatrix} t \\ t \end{pmatrix} + C\begin{pmatrix} \omega_{1}^{2}\sin\omega t \\ -\omega_{2}^{2}\sin\omega t \end{pmatrix} + D\begin{pmatrix} \omega_{1}^{2}\cos\omega t \\ -\omega_{2}^{2}\cos\omega t \end{pmatrix} $$
where $\omega = \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2}+\omega_{2}^{2}}$.
My question is, how can I proceed to find the particular solution(s)? Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Rewriting The ODE Into A First Order ODE

We can rewrite the differential equation into a first order equation
$ \dot{y}  = Ay +b $ with
$$
A= 
\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\- \omega_{1}^{2} & 0 & \omega_{1}^{2} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\\omega_{2}^{2} & 0 & - \omega_{2}^{2} & 0\end{matrix}\right],
 \quad 
b =\left[\begin{matrix}0\\a_{1}\\0\\a_{2}\end{matrix}\right].
$$
Where $y= (y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4)$ is so that $y_1 = x_1$ and $y_3=x_2$ in your notation. So the first row in $A$ just enforces $\dot{y_1} = y_2$ and so $\dot{y_2}= \ddot{x_1}$ and in the same way the third row enforces $\dot{y}_4 = \ddot{x}_2$.

### Solving The Homogeneous Equation

For any basis $(v_1, \dots , v_4)$ of $\mathbb{C}^4$ a basis of the solution space of the homogeneous equation $\dot{y}=Ay$ is given by $(e^{At}v_1, \dots , e^{At} v_4)$. As a basis we will use the generalized eigenvectors of $A$.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $$\lambda_1 = 0, \quad \lambda_2 =- i \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}, \quad
\lambda_3 = i \sqrt{ \omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}.$$

A basis of generalized eigenvectors of $A$ is:
$$
v_1 = \left[\begin{matrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right], \quad
v_2 = \left[\begin{matrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right], \quad
v_3 =\left[\begin{matrix}- \frac{i \omega_{1}^{2}}{\omega_{2}^{2} \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}\\- \frac{\omega_{1}^{2}}{\omega_{2}^{2}}\\\frac{i}{\sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}\\1\end{matrix}\right], \quad
v_4 = \left[\begin{matrix}\frac{i \omega_{1}^{2}}{\omega_{2}^{2} \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}\\- \frac{\omega_{1}^{2}}{\omega_{2}^{2}}\\- \frac{i}{\sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}\\1\end{matrix}\right],
$$
where $v_1$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$, $v_2$ is an eigenvector of $A^2$ with eigenvalue $0$ and $v_3,v_4$ are eigenvectors with eigenvalues $\lambda_2, \lambda_3$.

Now $e^{At}v_i$ is trivial to compute except for $v_2$. For $v_2$:
$$
e^{At}v_2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} A^n t^n v_2 =v_2 +  t A v_2 = v_2 +t v_1
$$
And therefore a basis $(\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_3, \varphi_4)$ of the solution space is defined by
$$
\varphi_1(t) = v_1, \quad \varphi_2(t) =v_2+ tv_1, \quad \varphi_3(t) =e^{\lambda_2 t} v_3,\quad \varphi_4(t) =  e^{\lambda_3 t} v_4.
$$

### Solving The Inhomogeneous Equation

#### General Solution

Let $\varphi_1 , \dots, \varphi_n$ be a basis of the solution space to some linear ODE of the form $\dot{y}=Ay$.
Let $\Phi$ be the matrix valued function $t \mapsto (\varphi_1(t), \dots , \varphi_n (t) )$. Then a solution $y_p$ to $ \dot{y}  = Ay +b $ is given by
$$
y_p(t) = \Phi(t)c(t)
$$
with
$$
c(t) = \int (\Phi^{-1})(t) \, b,
$$
where $\int(\Phi^{-1})$ is the indefinite integral.
This follows since
$$
\dot{y}_p(t) = \dot{(\Phi c)}(t) = \dot{\Phi}(t) c(t) + \Phi(t) \dot{c}(t)
= A \Phi(t)c(t) + \Phi(t) \Phi^{-1}(t) b= A y_p(t) +b.
$$
Any solution to the inhomogeneous equation is the sum of the particular solution $y_p$ and a homogeneous solution, because of the uniqueness of solution.

#### Application To The Specific ODE

Now i suspect that there might be a simple way of computing the above that exploits the simple form of $A$ (i.e. that 2 rows only enforce the derivatives). Maybe you or someone else can figure something out.
But i just bruteforced it using sympy:

Applied to the ODE in question (with rescaling of $v_3,v_4$):
$$
\Phi(t) = 
\left[\begin{matrix}1 & t & - \frac{i \omega_{1}^{2} e^{- i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{\sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}} & \frac{i \omega_{1}^{2} e^{i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{\sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}\\0 & 1 & - \omega_{1}^{2} e^{- i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}} & - \omega_{1}^{2} e^{i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}\\1 & t & \frac{i \omega_{2}^{2} e^{- i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{\sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}} & - \frac{i \omega_{2}^{2} e^{i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{\sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}\\0 & 1 & \omega_{2}^{2} e^{- i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}} & \omega_{2}^{2} e^{i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}\end{matrix}\right]
$$
and
$$
\Phi^{-1}(t) =
\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\omega_{2}^{2}}{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}} & - \frac{\omega_{2}^{2} t}{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}} & \frac{\omega_{1}^{2}}{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}} & - \frac{\omega_{1}^{2} t}{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}\\0 & \frac{\omega_{2}^{2}}{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}} & 0 & \frac{\omega_{1}^{2}}{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}\\\frac{i e^{i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}} & - \frac{e^{i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)} & - \frac{i e^{i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}} & \frac{e^{i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)}\\- \frac{i e^{- i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}} & - \frac{e^{- i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)} & \frac{i e^{- i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}} & \frac{e^{- i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)}\end{matrix}\right]
$$
which leads to
$$\int (\Phi^{-1}) (t) = \left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\omega_{2}^{2} t}{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}} & - \frac{\omega_{2}^{2} t^{2}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)} & \frac{\omega_{1}^{2} t}{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}} & - \frac{\omega_{1}^{2} t^{2}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)}\\0 & \frac{\omega_{2}^{2} t}{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}} & 0 & \frac{\omega_{1}^{2} t}{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}\\\frac{e^{i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)} & \frac{i e^{i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} & - \frac{e^{i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)} & - \frac{i e^{i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\\frac{e^{- i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)} & - \frac{i e^{- i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} & - \frac{e^{- i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)} & \frac{i e^{- i t \sqrt{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}}}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\end{matrix}\right].$$
Finally we obtain
$$
y_p(t) = 
\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\omega_{1}^{2} a_{2} \left(- 2 \omega_{1}^{2} - 2 \omega_{2}^{2} + t^{2} \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)^{2}\right) + a_{1} \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right) \left(2 \omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2} t^{2} \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)\right)}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)^{3}}\\\frac{t \left(\omega_{1}^{2} a_{2} + \omega_{2}^{2} a_{1}\right)}{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}\\\frac{\omega_{2}^{2} a_{1} \left(- 2 \omega_{1}^{2} - 2 \omega_{2}^{2} + t^{2} \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)^{2}\right) + a_{2} \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right) \left(\omega_{1}^{2} t^{2} \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right) + 2 \omega_{2}^{2}\right)}{2 \left(\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}\right)^{3}}\\\frac{t \left(\omega_{1}^{2} a_{2} + \omega_{2}^{2} a_{1}\right)}{\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2}}\end{matrix}\right].
$$
Of course we are really only interested in the first and third entry of $y_p$.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot!! The simplified expressions for your first and third entries are

$$ y_{1} = \frac{1}{2}\gamma t^{2} + \left(\frac{a_{1}-a_{2}}{\omega^{4}}\right)\omega_{1}^{2} $$

and

$$ y_{3} = \frac{1}{2}\gamma t^{2} - \left(\frac{a_{1}-a_{2}}{\omega^{4}}\right)\omega_{2}^{2} $$

where 

$$ \gamma = \frac{a_{1}\omega_{2}^{2} + a_{2}\omega_{1}^{2}}{\omega_{1}^{2}+\omega_{2}^{2}} = \frac{F_{1} + F_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}. $$ 

I like how your post is (somewhat) generalizable, so I wish more people saw it.

Comment: The full particular solution to my original problem is

$$ \vec{x}(t) = \frac{1}{2}\gamma t^{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + \frac{a_{1}-a_{2}}{\omega^{4}}\begin{pmatrix} \omega_{1}^{2} \\ -\omega_{2}^{2} \end{pmatrix} + a\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix} t \\ t \end{pmatrix} + c\begin{pmatrix} \omega_{1}^{2} \\ -\omega_{2}^{2} \end{pmatrix}\sin\omega t + d\begin{pmatrix} \omega_{1}^{2} \\ -\omega_{2}^{2} \end{pmatrix}\cos\omega t $$

where $a, b, c, d$ are undetermined constants.

Comment: The issue that gave me so much trouble is that I kept assuming the constant terms are the same in both entries (which isn't true in this case).

Comment: No problem! Yes the used method for the particular solution is very general, it can be used even when $A$ and $b$ depend on time. The only change in that case is to put $c = \int (\Phi^{-1} b)$. The only downside is the questionable computational efficiency. I think from my answer we can even infer that we can find a particular solution (to a problem like this one) with polynomials of a specific degree as the components since the exponentials always cancel each other. That might lead to a quicker solution by hand. I guess this is what you tried in essence.

Comment: Maximal Ideal - nice result. It's enlightening to look at what the different terms in the solution mean. The $1/2\gamma t^2$ is simply the whole system accelerating by the total force F1+F2. The $a$ and $b$ terms simply means that you didn't specify the initial position and velocity of the entire system (you can just set both $a$ and $b$ to 0 and say the system starts at rest at position 0). I think you can also discard the whole complicated term with $w^4$ in the denominator - that's also time-independent and just says where the whole system started.